# splwow64 deleting %TMP% permissions

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, permissions

Repeatedly I've had problems as a result from having all permissions set on the `%tmp%` folder (`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp`) (Win10) deleted.

As default the users/groups SYSTEM, the username itself and the administrators group should have permissions on that folder.

Manually restoring those permissions solves those problems at least temporary, nevertheless they are deleted at least every second day or so.

To find the reason of this I've set up auditing to log any permission changes on that folder, which resulted in the following event entry:

```
Permissions on an object changed.
Subject:
Security ID: <domainname>/<username>
Account Name: <username>
Account Domain: <domainname>
Logon ID: 0x586DD89

Object:
Object Server: Security
Object Type: File
Objektname: C:\Users\<username in 8.3 spec>\AppData\Local\Temp
Handle-ID: 0xd10

Prozess:
Prozess-ID: 0x1f08
Prozessname: C:\Windows\splwow64.exe

Permissions Change:
Original Security Descriptor:  D:PAI(A;OICI;0x1301ff;;;SY)(A;OICI;0x1301ff;;;S-1-5-21-2558324771-4217995790-2948301998-1151)
New Security Descriptor: D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROL"
```

I have no idea what to do about this. Does anyone have a clue why splwow64 would reset those permissions?

I don't think that this is a desired effect. sfc /scannow as well as a scan for malware/viruses didn't show up with anything. I'd gladly appreciate any hints at how to solve this.

Comment: Old question, but I have the same problem this week on a client's workstation. In my case, SPLWOW64 deleted the permissions yesterday, but Chrome deleted them today. So it's *not* a problem with the print spooler, that's a red herring. I'm going to recommend a full windows reload just to keep from wasting more hours on it.